# How to Update state using axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

How can I run my useEffect at top priority so that my state can be updated first then further processing can be done

I want my axios part should run first inside useEffect so that my state can be update first and then further I can use that.

Here  is error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
when I console it shows states is not updated it holds empty array

Here is mine code:

```
const initialState = {
    staff: [],
    isFetching: false,
    hasError: false
}

const Staff = ({ setStaffid }) => {
    const [states, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    console.log(states)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
        axios.get("https://example.com/staff")
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                console.log(response.data)
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCHSUCCESS",
                    payload: response.data.access
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCHFAILURE"
                });
            });
    }, );

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = states.staff[0].id;
        setStaffid(id);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Staff;
```

Comment: why you need multiple useEffect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because you are trying to access property 'id' on an `undefined` object.

Change `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const staff = states.staff[0];
  if(staff) setStaffid(staff.id);
}, [states.staff]);
```

To get rid of error just change your initialState.

```
const initialState = {
    staff: [{}],
    isFetching: false,
    hasError: false
}
```

Hope it helps.